# Sqlalchemy session.flush with threading

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am currently using scoped_session provided by sqlalchemy with autocommit=True and autoflush=True.

I notice that autoflush is no called properly as some of the updated results are not flushed when my script finishes executing.

Is autoflush not meant to be run with scoped_session in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: Is this the same script as your other question where you pass the `Request` objects around? Not sure if that might be related.

Answer (score 0):

> Is autoflush not meant to be run with scoped_session in a multithreaded environment?

there is no such restriction, no.

> I notice that autoflush is no called properly as some of the updated results are not flushed when my script finishes executing.

This is a misunderstanding of autoflush.  Autoflush is intended to flush pending data to the database before a query emits a SELECT to the database.  It does not provide the feature however that data is flushed immediately as each attribute of an object is changed, as this would be very inefficient and is not feasible with any kind of ORM, unit of work or not.    So if you modify a bunch of objects, then throw away the Session without further interaction with it, those pending changes are lost.

Autoflush is intended to be used within the context of a transaction.  In its default mode of usage, the Session begins a transaction for you, and you only need call commit() when a series of changes are ready to be finalized.   See the docs for background http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#flushing as well as the strong recommendations to **avoid autocommit** at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#autocommit-mode .